# draw part of image with openGL glDrawPixels

Tags: opengl

I have a function to draw an image in an `openGL` context. (used in that case to render to a texture) That works for the whole image, but should also be able to render only a rectangular part. Rendering parts works if the part has the same width as the image. For parts that are less wide than the image-data it fails.

Here is the function (reduced to only the part for small width, no cleanup,etc)

```
void drawImage(uint32 imageWidth, uint32 imageHeight, uint8* pData, 
               uint32 offX, uint32 partWidth)  // (offX+partWidth<=imageWidth)
{
    uint8* p(pData);
    if (partWidth != imageWidth)
    {
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, imageWidth);
        p = calcFrom(offX, pData); // point at pixel in row
    } 
    glDrawPixels(partWidth, ImageHeight, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p);
}
```

As said: `if (widthPart==imageWidth)` the rendering works fine. For some combinations of `partWidth` and `imageWidth` it works also but that seems to be a very special case, mainly width very small images and a some special `partWidths`.

I found no examples for this, but from the docs I think this shold be possible to do somehow like that. Did I missunderstand the whole thing, or have I just overseen a small pit-fall??

Thanks,
Moritz

P.S: it's running on windows
[Edited:] P.P.S: by now I have tried to do that as texture. If I replace  `glDrawPixels` with `glTexImage2D` I have the same problem...(could upload the whole image and render only part, but for small small parts of big pictures that might not e the best way...)

Comment: `glDrawPixels` is an old interface, I doubt it should be used. Upload your image to a texture, and use UV coordinates to only draw the part of the texture you need.

Answer (score 0):

AAArrrghh!!

GL_**UN**PACK_ROW_LENGTH not GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH!!!!